# how to set image as background button

Tags: android, button, background

I am new in Android development.I created a simple project with a simple button.I'd like to set image as background (see image). I've used android:src="@drawable/id_image" and android:background="@drawable/id_image2" but the image does not appear on the entire surface of button.Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: Simply you can use frame layout : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm

Answer (score 1):

Android, you can use [android.widget.ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) to display a normal “Button“, with a customized background image.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_btn_right_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `android:src` and `android:background` for adding two images.

Comment: I've used android:src="@drawable/" and android:background="@drawable" but the image does not appear on the entire surface of button

Comment: Did you put `android:src="@drawable` or `android:src="@drawable/id_of_your_image`?

Answer (score 0):

when you add your button , you just go to the menu of properties and choose background / drawable and choose your image

Comment: I've used android:src="@drawable/" and android:background="@drawable" but the image does not appear on the entire surface of button

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="your_background_goes_here"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="your_icon_above_background"/>

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="text_for_your_image"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```